# Can I Decrypt md5 in php?

Tags: php, encryption, md5

This is my encryption password.

```
$encrypted = md5($password);
```

Can I Decrypt it?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15194663/encrypt-and-decrypt-md5

Answer (score 4, accepted):

MD5 is a hash function, which are one-way functions (cannot be undone).

Whilst I would not recommend MD5 for password storage, if you want to verify that a password is correct you do not need to decrypt the hash. The idea is in order to verify a password is correct, rather than decrypting the hash, you encrypt the password given and compare the two hash values. If the two hash values are the same, then the two passwords are the same,