# Password recovery mail by PHP is not working

Tags: php, jquery, mysql

I am trying to create a script to recover passwords by mail, but it does not work. Previously It came with an error that the e-mail was invalid. 
Now its ends me the mail but with the `encrypted password` in it.
Please help me to decrypt the password
Any lead for this error is highly appreciable

```
  <?php
    require_once("config.php");    //Database Connection

    //Catch Field Data
    $email     =     $_POST['email'];
    $submitted    =    $_POST['submitted'];

    if($email) {
        $query        =    printf("SELECT * FROM registration where email='$email'");
        $result        =    mysql_query($query);
        $rowAccount    =    mysql_fetch_array($result);
    }

    if ($rowAccount) {

        $subject = "Your goprestige Username / Password Reminder";
        $headers = "From: info@abc.com";
        $fname = $rowAccount['fname'];
        $password = $rowAccount['password'];
        $msg = "<h1>My abc Admin</h1>
        <p>Hello '$user'!</p>
        <p>Here is the username/password reminder you requested. If you didn't request this reminder then don't panic too much, the likely hood of someone gaining access is minimal. Thank you abc </p>
        <p>Username: '$fname'</p>
        <p>Password: '$password'</p>
        <p>Many thanks, the abc Support Team.</p>
        ";

        $success = mail($email, $subject, $msg, $headers);

        if($success) {
            echo "<p id=errors>Reminder Success: Your Username and Password have been emailed to $email";
        }
    } else ($submitted) {
        echo '<p id="errors">Reminder Failed: The email you entered was not found on the system, please try again.</p>';
    }
?>
```

HTML

```
 <form class="form-horizontal ct-u-paddingBottom20" action="php/forget.php" method="post" id="passwd" style="display:none;">
                          <div class="form-group">
                                <label for="username" class="col-sm-2 control-label">Useremail: </label>
                                <div class="col-sm-10">
                                    <input type="text" class="form-control" id="email" name="email" placeholder="enter your email id" required>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                          <div>
                              <center>
                                  <span style="color:green;display:none;" class="success-footer"><h4 style="margin-left: 0px;">password link is sent  </h4></span>
                                  <span style="color:orange;display:none;" class="error-footer"><h4 style="margin-left: 0px;">invalid email</h4></span>
                                </center>
                          </div>
                          <div class="form-group">
                                <div class="col-sm-offset-2 col-sm-10">
                                     <p><input type="submit" value="Reset Password" /></p>
                                </div>
                            </div>


                       </form>
```

Javascript

```
<script type="text/javascript">

          var frm = $('#passwd');
          frm.submit(function (ev) {
              $.ajax({
                  type: frm.attr('method'),
                  url: frm.attr('action'),
                  data: frm.serialize(),
                  success: function (data) {
            //alert(data);
                      if (data) {
                        //alert('data');
                        $('.success-footer').css('display','block');
                      }
                      else{
                        $('.error-footer').css('display','block')
                      }
                  }
              });

              ev.preventDefault();

          });
      </script>
```

Comment: What is the error message you have encounter?

Comment: Check you filter_var() function if perform well on email validation

Comment: Where is your form? You are doing `var frm = $('#passwd');`, so is your `<form id="passw">` or is that the `id` for your password field? Have you looked at your browser console to see what your ajax is posting, and if it is sending a valid `email` value?

Comment: print $email & check what it returns, it seems to me that it is blank.

Comment: its the validation of email that if fall on if condition becomes true and not executing on else where sending email happens

Comment: @Sean yes my form id is "passw"...

Comment: @DipanwitaKundu i tried with that too... in both the code but still same error

Comment: .. Please don't use `MD5` to store passwords. Use [password_hash](http://php.net/manual/en/function.password-hash.php) to do this. Do note passwords are encrypted for a reason. Instead of trying to decrypt the current password you could just create and send a new password

Comment: so is by using password_hash it will send me the original password for that.?

Comment: You "can't" decrpyt passwords. It is "impossible" and you shouldn't do it. Alter your script so a new password is created or your user gets the option to choose a password him/herself

Comment: okey thank you... @DarkBee

Answer (score 1):

I'm assuming that your are using xampp to send the email. If that's the case, please follow the guidelines under in this discussion [How to configure XAMPP to send mail from localhost?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15965376/how-to-configure-xampp-to-send-mail-from-localhost) to configure your email settings.

here's the sample code

```
<?php
$Results['id'] = 1;
$message = "Your password reset link send to your e-mail address.";
$to      = 'your_email_id@gmail.com';
$subject = "Forget Password";
$from    = 'info@abc.com';
// $body    = 'Hi, <br/> <br/>Your Membership ID is '.$Results['id'].' <br><br>Click here to reset your password http://google.com/login-signup-in-php/reset.php?encrypt='.$encrypt.'&action=reset .';
$body    = "Hello";
$headers = "From: " . strip_tags($from) . "\r\n";
$headers .= "Reply-To: ". strip_tags($from) . "\r\n";
$headers .= "MIME-Version: 1.0\r\n";
$headers .= "Content-Type: text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1\r\n";

mail($to, $subject, $message, $headers);
?>
```

If you follow correctly the guidelines, try the given code above which basically from your code and removed temporarily some data which fetched from the database just to generate a test if mail is sending data. If successful, then it's the time you put it back to

```
if (condition) {
  # code...
} else {
  # code...
}
```

of your code.

Hope this help the problem

Comment: i tried with one it sends me the password but as my password is in md5.. so its comes with encrypted password .. how to decrypt that.

Comment: I see that's why invalid email address. This will help http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15194663/encrypt-and-decrypt-md5

Comment: i have edited my new code which is working but still with encrypted code ..please do help me

Comment: Still what is not working can you share the error you are getting;

Comment: @itzmukeshy7 as my code is encrypted in md5 so its comes with md5 code only... i want it to be original or cusomers can able to make a new passwrd for that.

Comment: Got it; create a reset password logic then and don't share even password hash it can be decrypted;

Answer (score 1):

Typically passwords are hashed, not encoded.  The difference is that a hash cannot be "unhashed" to bring back the original password. In the password saving function of your code, checkif you used the password_hash() function.  If you did, you can't get that password back.

That's actually a good thing because password reminders are generally an unsecure way of providing a "Forgot password" function.  See Troy Hunt's article on building a secure password reset function (http://www.troyhunt.com/2012/05/everything-you-ever-wanted-to-know.html)

A couple of solutions could be:

1) **Provide a one-time, time-limited use password** that they can use to change their password.  Ensure that only one of these are live at any moment.

2) **Provide a link to a unique url** that would allow the user to be challenged with something, such as a security question, to validate that they are not only the recipient of the email, but actually the person who requested the password change.

The second option would be more secure as it would provide an extra layer of validation at the cost, of course, of convenience to the user.

Answer (score -1):

Update your jquery ajax like this:

```
$.ajax({
  method: "POST",
  .....
})
```

because method is default: 'GET'

Comment: This is a comment, not an answer.

Comment: i tried with this new code it seems wrking for me.. but it sends me with encrypted md5 code.. how to change it with decrypted code in original code.

Comment: there is no way to decrypt md5() data.instead of send md5 password, send random generated password & ask him to rest by his own or generate a link for user & ask him to create his own password. or create password using your salt so that you can easily decrypt it..

Comment: OP used this in `$.ajax({type: frm.attr('method'),});` both have same meaning;

Comment: @itzmukeshy7, yes, You should use type if you're using versions of jQuery prior to 1.9.0. For more details please follow the link :http://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/

Comment: okey thank you @DipanwitaKundu ...will try to do as per your instruction

Comment: @DipanwitaKundu now `type` will work for every version but `method` not because `method` is added in 1.9.0; so be on safe side one should use `type` without any version consideration;

Comment: @DipanwitaKundu Creating your own salted password so you can decrypt them is such a bad advice. About the `MD5` comment that is not decryptable, which is true, but other [resources](https://www.freerainbowtables.com/tables2/) exist to retrieve MD5 hashes, so it better not to rely on MD5 anymore