# How to implement Crypt::encrypt method manually in PHP?

Tags: php, laravel, encryption, serialization, hash

I try to implement **Crypt::encrypt** function in **php** and this code is here:

```
$key = "ygXa6pBJOWSAClY/J6SSVTjvJpMIiPAENiTMjBrcOGw=";
$iv = random_bytes(16);
$value = \openssl_encrypt(serialize('123456'), 'AES-256-CBC', $key, 0, $iv);
bIv = base64_encode($iv);
$mac = hash_hmac('sha256', $bIv.$value, $key);
$c = ['iv'=>$bIv,'value'=>$value,'mac'=>$mac];
$json = json_encode($c);
$b = base64_encode($json);
```

But result is wrong.
I am thinking i should do something on $key before set in **openssl_encrypt** function.
Please help.
Thank you.

Comment: dear can you explain your Question it not clear what you asking about ?

Comment: Crypt::encrypt('123456');  i want implement this laravel function in pure php.    @recoverymen

Comment: see the answer below with 37 rate 

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15194663/encrypt-and-decrypt-md5

Comment: Result must be something like this: eyJpdiI6Im1RT2pLeHEyNXRmRkFialdnYlFBU0E9PSIsInZhbHVlIjoiOGduRnRjSkFjbWhvQlNIWlNKZU1jdz09IiwibWFjIjoiNzdmM2FlNTJhZjU3NmYxYWNkZDQ4NmFjM2MzYjEyZTNjZDI5MGI0OWVhYmMzNmQ4Mzg4NTRhOGU3MzA1ZTE4NyJ9

Comment: $key before using in encrypt function convert to something like this: ���I9d� V?'��U8�&���B$̌�8l���I9d� V?'��U8�&���B$̌�8l  i don't know what is this function that change $key.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40945983/how-to-implement-laravel-function-cryptencrypt-in-objective-c

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**SOLVED:**
We can implement this method like this:

```
$text = '123456';
$key = "ygXa6pBJOWSAClY/CFEdOTjvJpMIiPAMQiTMjBrcOGw=";
$key = (string)base64_decode($key);
$iv = random_bytes(16);
$value = \openssl_encrypt(serialize($text), 'AES-256-CBC', $key, 0, $iv);  
$bIv = base64_encode($iv);
$mac = hash_hmac('sha256', $bIv.$value, $key); 
$c_arr = ['iv'=>$bIv,'value'=>$value,'mac'=>$mac];
$json = json_encode($c_arr);
$crypted = base64_encode($json);
echo $crypted;
```

This work tor me.
**enjoy :)**
***Be Successful***

Comment: https://github.com/reza-khalafi/LaravelCrypt/blob/master/laravelEncrypt.php

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40945983/how-to-implement-laravel-function-cryptencrypt-in-objective-c

Answer (score 0):

Here is the implementation, directly from the [official source code](https://github.com/laravel/framework/blob/5.3/src/Illuminate/Encryption/Encrypter.php#L69).

```
public function encrypt($value)
{
    $iv = random_bytes(16);
    $value = \openssl_encrypt(serialize($value), $this->cipher, $this->key, 0, $iv);
    if ($value === false) {
        throw new EncryptException('Could not encrypt the data.');
    }
    // Once we have the encrypted value we will go ahead base64_encode the input
    // vector and create the MAC for the encrypted value so we can verify its
    // authenticity. Then, we'll JSON encode the data in a "payload" array.
    $mac = $this->hash($iv = base64_encode($iv), $value);
    $json = json_encode(compact('iv', 'value', 'mac'));
    if (! is_string($json)) {
        throw new EncryptException('Could not encrypt the data.');
    }
    return base64_encode($json);
}
```

- `$iv` should be the same as in the source
- `$this->key` is the encryption key you set in your .env file, **encoded in b64**
- `$this->cipher` should be the one you configured in your laravel configurations and compatible to your key-length.

---

In your example, you have set your `$key` to the value after the "base64:"-string, which is **not the key**. You need to encode the key with base64 before passing it.

So the the `$key` to the base64 encode of `ygXa6pBJOWSAClY/J6SSVTjvJpMIiPAENiTMjBrcOGw=`, which is `eWdYYTZwQkpPV1NBQ2xZL0o2U1NWVGp2SnBNSWlQQUVOaVRNakJyY09Hdz0K`