# Crypt in laravel Decrypt in react native Error

Tags: javascript, reactjs, laravel, react-native, cryptojs

I am creating an app with reactnative and laravel,

so my code in laravel is creating a Qr code with a crypted data and send it to my front end (Reactjs),

When i try o decrypted in react native using Crypto js it adds a few caractere that i didn't add in my back end ,

I will show all function and exmeples ,

//Code in laravel crypt my QR info

```
 $unix =time();     
 $unix_hashed =  Crypt::encrypt($unix);
 return  QrCode::size(100)->generate($unix_hashed);
```

// Code in react native with cryptojs for the decrypt

```
var key = '6AhFLqwlExB9tn2Twql62EtbFDqBEv+S7tXW3h6a/0o=';
let  encrypted = atob(data);
encrypted = JSON.parse(encrypted);
const iv = CryptoJS.enc.Base64.parse(encrypted.iv);
const value = encrypted.value;
key = CryptoJS.enc.Base64.parse(key);
var decrypted = CryptoJS.AES.decrypt(value, key, {
    iv: iv
  });
decrypted = decrypted.toString(CryptoJS.enc.Utf8);
```

// exemple of the output in console :

[this is my output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/47vt8.png)

but the problem it should be like this :

i:1634986874;

the " " & i & : & ; is extra

Can some one  help me

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`Crypt::encrypt()` uses AES-256 in CBC mode by default, s. [here](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/encryption#encrypting-a-value).

Before encryption, the plaintext is serialized by calling the PHP function [`serialize()`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.serialize.php) generating a storable representation of the value. For instance, `serialize(1635015182)` returns `i:1635015182;` and `serialize('Hello world')` returns `s:11: "Hello world";`. In the serialized data, `i` denotes an integer, `s:11` denotes an 11 character string.

If decryption is performed with `Crypt::decrypt()`, [`unserialize()`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.unserialize.php) is called after decryption, which deserializes the data and restores the original plaintext.

When decrypting with another library, such as CryptoJS, the deserialization is not performed, so the serialized plaintexts are returned. Therefore, deserialization must be done *manually* here.

Fortunately, there is the [*locutus*](https://github.com/locutusjs/locutus) library that provides ports of PHP functionalities to JavaScript, so `unserialize()` can also be executed under JavaScript/NodeJS without much effort:

```js
var CryptoJS = require('crypto-js');
var atob = require('atob');
var unserialize = require('locutus/php/var/unserialize')

// ciphertext from Crypt::encrypt()
var data = "eyJpdiI6IkYyaDhxenFJM0FjaW56TW83NkpuNHc9PSIsInZhbHVlIjoiNzhSeUs5em1WblpaRWk2OVBWVURnUT09IiwibWFjIjoiODg1NGFkOTk0MGVjMjIxODAyNzExOTgxYjhiMDM4YjliMmM5NzE5Mjc0YzFmNDVlMWU1MWRkMTQ2N2Q5ODdmNCJ9"

var key = '6AhFLqwlExB9tn2Twql62EtbFDqBEv+S7tXW3h6a/0o=';
let  encrypted = atob(data);
encrypted = JSON.parse(encrypted);
const iv = CryptoJS.enc.Base64.parse(encrypted.iv);
const value = encrypted.value;
key = CryptoJS.enc.Base64.parse(key);
var decrypted = CryptoJS.AES.decrypt(value, key, {
    iv: iv
  });
decrypted = decrypted.toString(CryptoJS.enc.Utf8);

// unserialize
console.log(decrypted); // i:1635015182;
console.log(unserialize(decrypted)); // 1635015182
```

The `unserialize()` call in the last line restores the original plaintext.

---

Please note that `encrypted.mac` contains a MAC for checking data integrity. [Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41327197/how-to-implement-cryptencrypt-method-manually-in-php/41344235#41344235) you can find a PHP implementation for `Crypt::encrypt()`.

Comment: Thank you so much for your answer it 100% correct and my code is decrypted correctly now huge thanks to you sir !

Comment: @RohitRathore - If still relevant, please post your code in a new question and describe the problem. If necessary, you can refer to this answer.